# PyMongo inserting takes too much time

Tags: python, python-3.x, insert, pymongo

I have a few ".csv" files which I would like to insert to my DB, but there is a lot of data and my code takes too much time. I would like to ask, if there is a different approach to inserting data like that? Btw. I don't want to use `os.system(mongoimport ... )` because it deletes front `0` from my phone columns.

here is the code

```py
def do_sync():
    path = "share"
    extension = ".csv"
    results = glob.glob(f"{path}/*{extension}")
    for result in results:
        print(result)
        csvfile = open(result, 'r')
        reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile )
        db=mongo_client.media_mongo
        header= [ "No", "phone", "location"]

        for each in reader:
            row={}
            for field in header:
                row[field]=each[field]

            db.main_hikanshou.insert(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the bulk insert function from [pymongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html)

You have to first create the insert queries and than send all of them to the database in one go.